# How do I assign styles to a php syntax

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, css

I want to give the input field the values that are in the css style script
I have this:

```
<script "javascript/text">
    var str1 = '<?php $this->form_validation->cc11_a?>';
    var str2 = '<?php $this->form_validation->cc11_b?>';
    var str3 = '<?php $this->form_validation->cc11_c?>';
    var str4 = '<?php $this->form_validation->cc11_d?>';

    if(str1 == 0){
        str1.style.background= '#fff';
        str1.style.color='#fff';
        str1.value=0;
    }else if(str1 == 1){
        str1.style.background= '#000';
        str1.style.color='#000';
        str1.value=1;
    }
</script>
```

I want to change the status of these input boxes with the data that I received in the above script. `<?php $this->form_validation->cc11_a?>` is getting a value but I don't know how to use it to give a status to what is being received.
in the html I have.

```
<input name="cc11_a" type="text" class="text" id="cc11_a" onclick="color(this.id);" style="width:0.3cm;" value="" />
<input name="cc11_b" type="text" class="text" id="cc11_b" onclick="color(this.id);" style="width:0.3cm;" value="" />
```

this means that if `<?php $this->form_validation->cc11_a?>` receives a 1 then it should apear as a black box.

Comment: Let me ask you this: can you apply styles to numbers? Because that's what you're trying to do when you say "apply styles to `str1` if `str1 == 0`".

Comment: You could give the element(s) your CSS class based on that PHP value, or have the JS assign the style, based on the value it gets from the PHP. A `switch` will also probably be easier than multiple `} else if {` with the same variable check. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/switch.

Comment: You are setting str1 to a string containing 1 or 0 i.e. `'1'` or `'0'` and testing it agains a numeric zero!

Comment: The answer that worked was taken down -.- i'll post what I did plus the answer that worked

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion you are doing it the wrong way.  Why are you assigning styles using javascript?

In my personal experience you can and should do that only through server side language (php in your case).

The rule of thumb is the following: if the dynamic behaviour(styling in your case) of your page depends on configuration you should develop that with server side language,  if the behaviour depends on user interaction you should do that using js.

If you use php you can:

- directly print styles on node class attributes.
- print a css formatted style in a  tag.
- use conditional styling with a css preprocessor like sass or less.

Answer (score 0):

```
function colores(){

    var str1 = '<?php 
    if ($this->form_validation->cc11_a == 1 )
    { echo '1';}
    else if($this->form_validation->cc11_a == 0 ){ echo '0';}
    ?>';
    var str2 = '<?php 
    if ($this->form_validation->cc11_b == 1 )
    { echo '1';}
    else if($this->form_validation->cc11_b == 0 ){ echo '0';}
    ?>';
    var str3 = '<?php 
    if ($this->form_validation->cc11_c == 1 )
    { echo '1';}
    else if($this->form_validation->cc11_c == 0 ){ echo '0';}
    ?>';
    var str4 = '<?php 
    if ($this->form_validation->cc11_d == 1 )
    { echo '1';}
    else if($this->form_validation->cc11_d == 0 ){ echo '0';}
    ?>';

    if(str1 == 0){
        $('#cc11_a').css({'background-color':"#fff", 'color':"#fff"}).val("0");
    } else if(str1 == 1){
        $('#cc11_a').css({'background-color':"#000", 'color':"#000"}).val("1");
    }
    if(str2 == 0){
        $('#cc11_b').css({'background-color':"#fff", 'color':"#fff"}).val("0");
    } else if(str1 == 1){
        $('#cc11_b').css({'background-color':"#000", 'color':"#000"}).val("1");
    }
    if(str3 == 0){
        $('#cc11_c').css({'background-color':"#fff", 'color':"#fff"}).val("0");
    } else if(str1 == 1){
        $('#cc11_c').css({'background-color':"#000", 'color':"#000"}).val("1");
    }
    if(str4 == 0){
        $('#cc11_d').css({'background-color':"#fff", 'color':"#fff"}).val("0");
    } else if(str1 == 1){
        $('#cc11_d').css({'background-color':"#000", 'color':"#000"}).val("1");
    }
}


<td colspan="3" style="text-align:left">
    <input name="cc11_a" type="text" class="text" id="cc11_a" onclick="color(this.id);" style="width:0.3cm;" value="" />
    <input name="cc11_b" type="text" class="text" id="cc11_b" onclick="color(this.id);" style="width:0.3cm;" value="" />
    <input name="cc11_c" type="text" class="text" id="cc11_c" onclick="color(this.id);" style="width:0.3cm;" value="" />
    <input name="cc11_d" type="text" class="text" id="cc11_d" onclick="color(this.id);" style="width:0.3cm;" value="" />
</td>
```